# AWS Opensearch - Index Design

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am new to AWS Opensearch and have data sitting in RDS. The RDS data model is Star Schema. This data will need to be feed into the AWS Opensearch cluster. For the Index designing - Is it safe to say that we can create one Index per Dimension table or rather for each Dimension for which we expect user to search on? Or Shall we start with one Index which is a flattened view of the Star Schema (This will create lot of redundancy). Any advise is appreciated. Thanks in advance.